# Docker Windows Container Access is denied issue

Tags: docker, windows-container

OS: Windows
Docker Desktop version: Server: Docker Desktop 4.7.1 (77678)
Expected behavior: Once i run the following command to successfully download, extract and install windows images in my system.
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
Actual behavior: But after the command downloads the required files, it fails to extract the files downloaded.
following is the error message.
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from windows/servercore/iis
18ae6bebe21d: Extracting [==================================================>] 1.505GB/1.505GB
44a67477f452: Download complete
05fb313bfe29: Download complete
4c76990685f7: Download complete
76b228c93fc3: Download complete
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: Failed to safefile.OpenRelative failed in Win32: open \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\bf3bb885a2ba9a455358c0e5b6ea9e798b2ee86ecfb051c9720c96f9be1ab171\Files\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\f686aace6942fb7f7ceb231212eef4a4_178ff1a9-3d56-4fd5-837f-465774da8d9d: Access is denied. (0x1f) Files\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\f686aace6942fb7f7ceb231212eef4a4_178ff1a9-3d56-4fd5-837f-465774da8d9d
Steps to reproduce: Running command to pull any of the windows image.
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
Diagnostics id: 4EE91621-E6F2-4FCE-BF04-0CBB06362D06

Comment: tried pulling different images specific to windows version, still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has surfaced on many other cases. The root cause seems to be (in most cases) related to Antivirus blocking the extract process to happen correctly because it incorrectly flags the operation as a virus.

Can you confirm what is your AV and if you have any real time scan happening?